# Moving Average of a variable frequency signal

Tags: c, average, sensors, moving-average

I was using this code to get the moving average of a sinusoidal Realtime wave with a constant frequency. (test_ sin being a sin wave with a constant frequency). I was sampling 100 samples as it can be seen in LENGTH_X = 100 and Buffer_X[100].

```
static double test_sin = 0; 
static double sum_x = 0 , filter_out_X = 0 ;
static int LENGTH_X = 100 , counter_filter_X = 0 ;
static double Buffer_X[100]= {0} ;
.
.
.
sum_x = sum_x + test_sin - Buffer_X\[counter_filter_X\];
filter_out_X = sum_x / LENGTH_X ;
Buffer_X\[counter_filter_X\] = (test_sin);
counter_filter_X = counter_filter_X+1 ;
if (counter_filter_X == LENGTH_X)
{
counter_filter_X = 0 ;
}
```

Basically i followed this reference to make the algorithm here on Youtube:
[efficient Moving Average Filter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xv6qk8q1PA&t=476s)

The question i want to ask is how can I alter this code such that i can change the samples.

My sin wave has a variable frequency so i want to keep the LENGTH_X and BUffer_X[] variable or changing as well not just 100 samples.
i already know the samples how much to keep.

Once I set Length_X =100 and Buffer_X[100]= {0} it gets stuck to 100 samples even if later i try to re initialize it,it does not re initialize as well.

I tried simple things like initializing in a different manner:

```
if(freq>1000)
{
static int LENGTH_X = 100 , counter_filter_X = 0 ;
static double Buffer_X[100]= {0} ;
}
else
{
static int LENGTH_X = 10 , counter_filter_X = 0 ;
static double Buffer_X[10]= {0} ;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem for which a moving average may not be the most appropriate solution.  What are you actually trying to determine?  If you are trying to determine the mean DC level, an IIR low-pass filter with a cut-off frequency well below the lowest expected frequency of the input would do better.  Certainly you should never try to adapt the filter to the input, as in most useful cases, the input would be unknown.  The first important information in designing a suitable filter are the sampling rate, and the signal bandwidth (min and max frequency in the signal).

Comment: @Clifford If tweaked appropriately, a moving average software filter should act just as a hardware (RC) lowpass filter though. With a tight budget, it is feasible to do it in software to reduce BoM costs. Same thing with switch debouncing.

Comment: @Lundin of course; it is a special case of an FIR filter, but my point is knowledge of the actual requirement and nature of the input may present a more effective solution.  I am not suggesting a hardware solution, and and IIR is more memory efficient and without the n/2 delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code for changing number of samples won't work. The variables defined inside the `if-else` part will not be accessible after the `if-else`.

If supported on your system you could use variable length arrays and `memset`. Like:

```
int LENGTH_X;
int counter_filter_X = 0;
if(freq>1000)
{
    LENGTH_X = 100;
}
else
{
    LENGTH_X = 10;
}
double Buffer_X[LENGTH_X];  // variable length array
memset(Buffer_X, 0, LENGTH_X * sizeof Buffer_X[0]); // zero initialize
```

Or you can go for dynamic allocated memory. Like

```
int LENGTH_X;
int counter_filter_X = 0;
if(freq>1000)
{
    LENGTH_X = 100;
}
else
{
    LENGTH_X = 10;
}
double* Buffer_X = calloc(LENGTH_X, sizeof Buffer_X[0]);  // dynamic zero-initialized memory
```

That said I would consider if there is a reason for changing array size at run time. If you know a maximum for `LENGTH_X` just make the array that maximum size and only use the part of the array you currently want. Re-initializing can be done using `memset` as shown above.

Maybe your code could look like:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 1000
...
...
double test_sin = 0; 
double sum_x = 0;
double filter_out_X = 0 ;
int LENGTH_X = 100;
int counter_filter_X = 0;
double Buffer_X[MAX_LENGTH]= {0} ;

while(keep_running)
{
    if (change_length)
    {
        sum_x = 0;
        counter_filter_X = 0;
        if(freq>1000)
        {
             LENGTH_X = 100;
        }
        else
        {
            LENGTH_X = 10;
        }
        memset(Buffer_X, 0, LENGTH_X * sizeof Buffer_X[0]);
    }

    test_sin = get_sample();

    sum_x = sum_x + test_sin - Buffer_X[counter_filter_X];
    filter_out_X = sum_x / LENGTH_X ;
    Buffer_X[counter_filter_X] = test_sin;
    counter_filter_X = counter_filter_X+1 ;
    if (counter_filter_X == LENGTH_X)
    {
        counter_filter_X = 0 ;
    }

    ...
    ...

    freq = ...;
    change_length = ...;
}
```

Here you'll have add some code for updating `freq` and `change_length`

Comment: Aside: `memset(Buffer_X, 0, LENGTH_X * sizeof Buffer_X[0]);` is clearer written as `memset(Buffer_X, 0, sizeof Buffer_X);` since `Buffer_X` is an array.